# Data sources in CDKTF

Tags: typescript, terraform, cdktf

I am trying to replicate one of my simple stacks from HCL to TypeScript (using CDKTF), I am having issues setting up a data source to get a list of AMIs. This is what I am trying to do:

```
const amis = new ec2.DataAwsAmiIds(this, "ami-ids", {
  owners: ["amazon"],
  nameRegex: "^amzn2-ami-hvm-*-x86_64-ebs",
  filter: [{
    name: "name",
    values: ["amzn2-ami-hvm-*-x86_64-ebs"]
  }]
});
```

I then try to reference this like so:

```
const instance = new ec2.Instance(this, "instance", {
  instanceType: "t2.micro",
  ami: `${amis.id}`,
  ...
```

The issue I am having is that this value will be a Token (`${TfToken[TOKEN.1]}`), how to I get the string value from this in order to be able to pass it in? Thanks.

The same thing applies to generating a key pair using the TLS provider, here is the complete [source code](https://github.com/mkm29/cdktf-ec2/blob/main/main.ts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ec2.DataAwsAmiIds` will have attribute of `ids`; during synth time you'll see it represented as a Token but it will render as the terraform reference in the  terraform JSON. The reason it is a Token is because it represents information that will only be known during/after Terraform runtime, can see more info here: https://www.terraform.io/cdktf/concepts/tokens#tokens

Comment: Thanks! I replaced the value of ami with `Fn.element(amis.ids, 0).toString()`. I still cannot figure out how to save the private key without the token, should I create a TerraformOutput with the key? If so CDKTF will not allow output of sensitive data